# Using pytest for OOPS where one class calls another and calls another

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I am a noob at writing unit testing and I have not been able to find the answer anywhere for the following purpose

```py
class xLoader:
    def __init__(self, config, request_id,logger, mongo_obj,data_in):
        self.config = config
        self.logger = Logger(self.__class__.__name__, config["env"])
        self.request_id = request_id 
        self.created_by = None  
        self.mongos = mongos  
        self.data_in = data_in
        self.get_new_loc_models()

    def get_new_loc_models(self):
        self.yrefiner = YRefiner(self.data_in)
        return self.yrefiner.get_new_models()

    def create_metadata_model(self):
        refined_log_models = [obj for obj in self.get_loc_refined_models() if obj.is_data_valid()]
```

Now that I have a class like this, I would like to write unit testing for the above.

I realise that I have to first start off by writing unit testing for initialisation of the object and making sure all data validations pass.

But the confusing bit comes in when I have to call `get_new_loc_models`. Over here, do I test just for the return value? Do I mock the object of the `YRefiner` class? Do I actually call the function, get the response and assert it to a value?

Is there any other testing that I am missing out on? I just don't understand when I need to create a mock and when I do not.
Below is testing I have written already

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_config():
    return {"env": "test"}

@pytest.fixture
def mock_logger():
    return MockLogger()

def test_get_loc_refined_models(mock_config, mock_logger):

    request_id = "123"
    mongo_obj= MagicMock()
    data_in= "mock_data_here"
    loader = xLoader(mock_config, request_id, mock_logger, mongos, data_in)

    # Act
    refined_models = loader.get_new_loc_models()


    assert refined_models is not None
def test_create_metadata_model(mock_config, mock_logger):

    request_id = "123"
    mongo_obj= MagicMock()
    data_in= "mock_data_here"
    loader = xLoader(mock_config, request_id, mock_logger, mongos, securevault, log_data, log_source)

    metadata_model = loader.create_metadata_model()
```

Am I doing this right? If not, how do I need to be looking at things when I am unit testing. We have a bit of a complex OOP strucuture where `xLoader`  -> `YRefiner` -> `ZParser` -> Finally returns the actual result. Hence why I am wondering how to do this